# Running a raw query with parameter bindings has no result

Tags: sql, laravel

My sql statement returns null after using DB Raw.No data is produced after passing the request to postman

```php
$current_lat = $request->latitude;
$current_lng = $request->longitude;
$car_type = $request->car_type;

$raw = DB::Raw("(3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(('.$current_lat.' - artisans.driver_lat)
     * pi()/180 / 2), 2)+ COS('.$current_lat.' * pi()/180 ) 
     * COS(artisans.driver_lat * pi()/180)
     * POWER(SIN(('.$current_lng.' - artisans.driver_lng) 
     * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )))");

return json_encode($raw);
```

The results is: `{}`

When I try querying directly in the database, it returns an output as:

```
4
0.03677850072504271
6.6701784633102145
-1.562010571360574
```

Comment: is it a query for lunching a missile?

Comment: no pls,haversine query used in uber

Comment: just kidding, check my answer ;)

Comment: I have commented with the error i got

Comment: Why not [check the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions)? You are missing `select()`, and `get()`.  Even just searching for your keywords turns up excellent examples here on SO, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50398877/laravel-query-builder-selectraw-or-select-and-raw), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821421/why-to-use-dbraw-inside-dbselect-in-laravel).

Answer (score 0):

Try `DB::select` like this:

```php
$results = DB::select('select (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((? - artisans.driver_lat)
 * pi()/180 / 2), 2)+ COS(? * pi()/180 ) 
 * COS(artisans.driver_lat * pi()/180)
 * POWER(SIN((? - artisans.driver_lng) 
 * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) from artisans', [$current_lat, $current_lat, $current_lng]);
```

This also provides protection against SQL injection. Check [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/database#running-queries) for more info.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':$current_lat * pi()/180 )

Comment: @reaspider typo fixed, try again.

Comment: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((:current_lat - artisans.driver_lat)\n * pi()/180 / 2), 2)+ COS(:current_lat * pi()/180 ) \n * COS(artisans.driver_lat * pi()/180)\n * POWER(SIN((:current_lng - artisans.driver_lng) \n * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) from artisans)"

Comment: DB::select("
select (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(($current_lat - artisans.driver_lat)
 * pi()/180 / 2), 2)+ COS($current_lat * pi()/180 )  * COS(artisans.driver_lat * pi()/180)
 * POWER(SIN(($current_lng - artisans.driver_lng)  * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) from artisans");

Answer (score 0):

I think it should look like this

```
DB::table('artisans')
    ->select(DB::Raw("your raw"))
    ->get();
```